# About compilation unit and Schwarz Counter and singleton pattern

Tags: c++, singleton

I look this example and practice it:
https://novus.pixnet.net/blog/post/23784820

(The code is at the end)

The compile command is:

```
g++ sc.cc main.cc -o main.exe
```

I have 2 questions:

1. The Compilation Unit has 2 unit which consist of sc and main. (correct?)
2. I know this example (Schwarz Counter) is applied to iostream (C++).**Singleton pattern** looks suitable for this situation. Does **Singleton pattern** is better than **Schwarz Counter** in the case for unique and global (such as file io)?

### Code:

sc.h

```cpp
#include <fstream>

class Log {
friend class Initializer;
public:
   void Print(const char* msg) {
      std::fputs(msg, onlyFile_);
   }

private:
   static std::FILE* onlyFile_;
};

class Initializer {
public:
   Initializer();
   ~Initializer();
private:
   static int ref_;
};

extern Log log;
static Initializer init;
#endif
```

sc.cc

```
#include "s.h"

std::FILE* Log::onlyFile_ = 0;
int Initializer::ref_ = 0;

Initializer::Initializer() {
   if (0 == ref_++) {
      Log::onlyFile_ = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
   }
}

Initializer::~Initializer() {
   if (0 == --ref_) {
      fclose(Log::onlyFile_);
   }
}
```

main.c

```cpp
#include "s.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  log.Print("aa");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "Singleton pattern" is an *anti pattern*. Don't ever use it, *please*. It will cause you much future pain.

Comment: Hi @ Jesper Juh .Thanks for your suggestion. But I read lot of C++ book which recommend reader using singleton pattern in this case. I know "Singleton pattern" is not safe in multi-thread. But there are lots of solution for it. I wish you provide some example(bad case), thank you :)

Comment: Go ahead and use it if you like. Then in 5-10 years when you are sick of fixing bugs caused by tight coupling, indeterminate instanciation order, shutdown crashes caused by a singleton holding on to a resource, etc etc etc. Then come back. Do whatever you want. I'm just telling you that based on *my* 30+ years of experience with C++ - the Singleton pattern is going to cause you *grief*. A Singleton is basically just a glorified global variable - you've learned why those are bad, right? But, whatever, learn yourself. Have fun debugging strange crashes and weird variable changes.

Comment: Thank @Jesper Juhl! I got it. This situation is the first time I heard.